# Can't run project through SVN

Tags: php, apache, svn, xampp

After successful configuration of svn, my localhost with svn

> localhost/svn/myPhpProject

shows me folder tree instead of running the project.

If i click on index.php from tree structure that is displayed on browser it actually load the script within the file rather then Executing the script. I have followed this link

for my SVN configuration [Configure Svn on win envoirment](http://www.inetsolution.com/turnleft/post/How-to-Setup-Subversion-2b-Apache-2b-WebSVN-on-Windows.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design.

SVN is a source control system, not a deployment system.

If you want to deploy your application, then `svn export` it, then publish it to a server configured for it.

If you want to deploy it every time a change is committed to SVN then use a [post commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) or a CI server such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). (Only do this to deploy to test servers, don't deploy things willy nilly to live).

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin said - SVN wasn't built for the way you are using it. I use git which is different but the same kind of principle. Just set up SVN repo on your live server and export it when and update is needed.